# Change Basemap Colors in Masked Regions (matplotlib)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, colors, matplotlib-basemap

My basemap color is defaulted to black.  However, I would like to have the basemap color be white in the areas where I have masked (negative) precipitation values set to black (high latitudes of an image in my case).  I could change the alpha on set_bad, but that gives me a non-preferred color of grey.  Is this easily doable?  I would post an image but I don't have 10 reputation points yet. TIA.

```
datamasked = np.ma.masked_where(datam < 0.0, datam)

my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap',uneven_rgb)
my_cmap.set_bad('k', 1.0)

mapproj = Basemap(projection = 'cyl', llcrnrlat=-90.0, llcrnrlon=0.0, urcrnrlat=90.0,     urcrnrlon=360.0)

mapproj.drawcoastlines()
mapproj.drawcountries()
mapproj.drawparallels(np.array([-60.0, -30.0, 0.0, 30.0, 60.0]), labels=[0,0,0,0])
mapproj.drawmeridians(np.array([0.0, 90.0, 180.0, 270.0, 360.0]), labels=[0,0,0,0])

myplot = plt.imshow(datamasked.T, interpolation = 'nearest', cmap = my_cmap, \
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0.0, vmax = 20.0, clip = False), \
    extent = (0.0, 360.0, -90.0, 90.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Very easily doable. Just change the color in set_bad to anything other than 'k' (i.e. black). Any recognized colors in Matplotlib will work. No need to change the alpha values.

I.e. to change the masked values to magenta: 
my_cmap.set_bad('magenta', 1.0)